How to combine two dataframe one as header and other has rows
df 1:
0         AREA
1       DETAIL
2             
3       ACTION
4     COMMENTS
5        MEDIA

df 2:
                     0  ... 6
0  Back\nYard/Exterior  ...  
1          Dining Room  ...  
2                Entry  ...  
3                Entry  ...  
4     Garage/Parki\nng  ...  
5     Garage/Parki\nng  ... 

code:
df1 = table1[0].df
header = df1.iloc[0]
headers = header.values.tolist()
df2 = table2[0].df
df2.to_csv('my_csv.csv', columns=headers)

Required solution:
    AREA                DETAIL                ACTION     COMMENTS     MEDIA
    
   Back\nYard/Exterior  ...  
          Dining Room  ...  
                Entry  ...  
                Entry  ...  
     Garage/Parki\nng  ...  
     Garage/Parki\nng  ... 

Is there any solution to get df1 as the header by combining df1 and df2. df2.to_csv('my_csv.csv', columns=headers) is showing error KeyError: "None of [Index(['\uf279 AREA', '\uf276 DETAIL', '\uf2c8', '\uf7d9 ACTION', '\uf27a COMMENTS', '\uf87c MEDIA'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]". Is there any solution

this might work:
import pandas as pd

data1 = {"col1": [" AREA", " DETAIL", "", " ACTION", " COMMENTS", " MEDIA"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)

headers = df1.iloc[:, 0].tolist()

data = {'col1': ["Back\nYard/Exterior", "Dining Room", "Entry", "Entry", "Garage/Parki\nng", "Garage/Parki\nng"],
        'col2': [0] * 6,
        'col3': [0] * 6,
        'col4': [0] * 6,
        'col5': [0] * 6,
        'col6': [0] * 6}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'], index=range(6))
df.columns = headers
df.head()


